# C++ using a class from a different file

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, interface

I am trying to write a series of programs that use the same main (main.cpp) file, but with different secondary source files (object1.cpp, object2.cpp, etc). So I will be compiling them essentially like this:

```
g++ -o program1.exe main.cpp object1.cpp
g++ -o program2.exe main.cpp object2.cpp
```

What I want to do is have objectN.cpp define a class with certain methods implemented, which will be called from the main file. The source codes look something like this:

header file (object.hpp)

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_OBJECT_HPP
#define INCLUDE_OBJECT_HPP

class MyObjectInterface
{
public:
  MyObjectInterface();
  virtual ~MyObjectInterface() {};
  virtual void MethodA() = 0;
  virtual void MethodB() = 0;
};

#endif
```

object1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "object.hpp"

using namespace std;

class MyObject : public MyObjectInterface
{
private:
  int member;

public:
  MyObject(int a)  { member = a; }
  void MethodA() { cout << member << endl; }
  void MethodB() { cout << member*2 << endl; }
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "object.hpp"

using namespace std;

MyObjectInterface *x;

int main()
{
  x = new MyObject(1);
  x->MethodA();
  x->MethodB();
  return 0;
}
```

object2.cpp would have a similar structre to object1.cpp but the class would have different data members.

I can't get this to work, because I need to include the the class declaration of MyObject in main.cpp. But each object*.cpp file will declare the MyObject class with different members, so I cannot just simply make a seperate object.hpp header and include it in main, because I need different headers for different objects. The only thing main should have to know about is the methods.

I hope I've explained the problem clearly; if not leave a comment and I'll try to clarify. It seems like there should be a really simple way of doing something like this but I can't figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: You should have a look at the [Factory design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), that'll be useful to create your concrete classes used with main().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> can't get this to work, because I need to include the the class declaration of MyObject in main.cpp

NO you don't. Make a factory method

*.h:

```
MyObjectInterface* makeObject();
```

*.cpp:

```
MyObjectInterface* makeObject(){
    return new MyObject;
}
```

However, having identically named classes with identical structure declared in different files might confuse *some* compilers in certain circumstances (rare thing, but it can happen).

Also, better solution would be to rethink your program structure. Because your derived classes are supposed to have different data members, it means you'll probably need to access those data members. Because you'll probably need to access those memebrs, then you'll need to know *something* about that class, so you'll have to put its declaration into header.

Another problem is that class represents some kind of concept, so picking unique name should be fairly trivial. If you have many different classes with SAME name, you might have a design problem - your classes do not represent unique concepts, and you create too many classes needlessly.

Comment: +1 for good advice, even though the OP didn't know it was needed

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that worked.

As for changing the program structure - I agree this is not necessarily the best. However the code I put in OP is just an example of the problem. The actual program I am working on is much larger and it will take too much effort to restructure the code.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is to declare this function in `object.hpp`:

```
MyObjectInterface * createInstance();
```

and implement it like this in the two `.cpp` files:

```
MyObjectInterface * createInstance() {
    return new MyObject();
}
```

and replace

```
x = new MyObject(1);
```

by

```
x = createInstance();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, even though someone else gave the same answer 1 minute before :P

Comment: @smead: Actually, I answered 28 seconds before him/her (hover over the "X hours ago" text, and you'll see the timestamp) - he did provide some useful advice in addition, though, so he deserves to get the accepted answer.